# How do I get the list of all the versions of a package?

Tags: chocolatey

I would like to get the list of versions of a package. What is the command line for this?

It would be also nice to search in versions, for example: all the versions that are higher or lower than a specific version.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Update: [Since v2.0.0](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/new-in-v2#the-list-command-only-shows-local-packages) of chocolatey the command is

```
 choco search --exact <packagename> --all
```

(Credit: Podbrushkin's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393803/3102305)

For versions prior to v2.0.0, you can just add the `--all` to the end of your request.
You can also add `-v` for verbose output.

`Choco list packagename --all`

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I was also trying to find this switch.

Comment: This does not list pre releases or release candidates. How would you list these?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett `--pre` - https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-list

Comment: this is returning a list of packages that are beyond my packagename

Comment: You can now use `-e` as mentioned in another post. I'll update this answer to cover that.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. For instance: `choco list dotnet -e --all` only shows `Chocolatey v0.10.15
dotnet 5.0.4 [Approved]
1 packages found.` but not the other available versions (like 5.0.0).

Comment: This is a known issue with choco CLI v0.10.15. It is fixed with a beta prerelease available.

Answer (score 18):

Update: [Since v2.0.0](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/new-in-v2#the-list-command-only-shows-local-packages) of chocolatey the command is

```
choco search -e <package> -a
```

(Credit: Podbrushkin's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393803/3102305)

For versions prior to v2.0.0 it was:

```
choco list -e <package> -a
```

-e, --exact

Only return packages with this exact name.

<s>choco list --by-id-only [package] -a</s>

--by-id-only

Only return packages where the id contains the search filter.

Answer (score 8):

Now it's `choco search -e packagename -a`.

`-e` is for "exact name", `-a` is for "all".

Old methods don't work anymore:

```
PS C:\Users\user> choco list -e python -a
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Invalid argument -a. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.
PS C:\Users\user> Choco list python --all
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Invalid argument --all. This argument has been removed from the list command and cannot be used.
```